# function isIsogram not working correctly

Tags: javascript

Create a function called isIsogram that takes one argument, a word to test if it's an isogram. This function should return a boolean indicating whether it is an isogram (true) or not (false) in Javascript. Here is my code:

```
function isIsogram(word){
    if (word !== 'string'){
      return 'Argument should be a string';
    }

    if (word === ' '){
      return false;
    }

    else{
      var str = word.toLowerCase();
      for(var i=0; i<str.length;i++){
        if (charAt[i]>1){
          return false;
        }
        else{
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(isIsogram('Dermatoglyphics'));
```

The code however returns 'Argument, not a string' for Dermatoglyphics which it ought not to

Comment: `word !== 'string'` that's not how you do a type check. Take a look at [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator

Answer (score 0):

its working fine

whats problem you have face

you pass argu `Dermatoglyphics` is != to `string` thats why if condition true and give message `Argument should be a string` and return

```js
function isIsogram(word) {
  if (word !== 'string') {
    return 'Argument should be a string';
  }

  if (word === ' ') {
    return false;
  } else {
    var str = word.toLowerCase();
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      if (charAt[i] > 1) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(isIsogram('Dermatoglyphics'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to check if a letter appears just on times, then you could use an object and take a flag for every found letter. By checking the `letter` object, the function exit with false if a duplicate letter is found.

```js
function isIsogram(word) {
    var str = word.toLowerCase(),
        letter = Object.create(null),
        i;

    if (typeof word !== 'string') {
        return 'Argument should be a string';
    }

    if (word === ' ') {
        return false;
    }
  
    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (letter[str[i]]) {
            return false;
        }
        letter[str[i]] = true;
    }
    return true;
}

console.log(isIsogram('Dermatoglyphics'));
```

Comment: The code runs well now. Thanks, but how do I write the typeOf operator correctly from the original code?

Comment: @danoseun, what do you mean by writing it correctly? you could write it as above.

Comment: I know but I just want to be sure of how to do a type check using typeOf operator.

Comment: `typeof` is all with small characters. the check is done with the `typeof` oparator, the item to check and then compare it with as string of the type, as written here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: Oh I see the mistake,typeOf instead of typeof.thanks